# Use Ito's formula for calculate the dynamics of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider this stochastic differential equation:
$$()=−a()+σ(),\quad (0)=_0∈ \Bbb R$$
where $a$ and $σ$ are constants and $(t)$ is a Brownian motion.

Can someone show me how to use the Ito's formula for the dynamics of $e^{at}X(t)$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stochastic process described by
$$
\mathrm{d}X_t = \mu_t(X_t)\mathrm{d}t + \sigma_t(X_t)\mathrm{d}W_t, 
\quad\mathrm{where}\quad 
\begin{cases}
   \mu_t(x) = -ax \\
   \sigma_t(x) = \sigma = const
\end{cases},
$$
to which you want to apply the transformation $\varphi(x,t) = e^{at}x$, hence thanks to Itô's lemma :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
   \mathrm{d}\varphi(X_t,t) &=&\displaystyle
   \left(\dot{\varphi}(X_t,t) + \mu_t(X_t)\varphi'(X_t,t) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_t(x_t)^2\varphi''(X_t,t)\right)\mathrm{d}t + \sigma_t(X_t)\varphi'(X_t,t)\mathrm{d}W_t \\
   \mathrm{d}(e^{at}X_t) &=&\displaystyle
   \left(ae^{at}X_t - aX_t\cdot e^{at} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\cdot0\right)\mathrm{d}t + \sigma\cdot e^{at}\mathrm{d}W_t \\
   &=&\displaystyle \sigma e^{at}\mathrm{d}W_t 
\end{array}
$$
where $\dot{\varphi} = \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}$ and $\varphi' = \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}$. In consequence, one finds :
$$
X_t = e^{-at}\left(x_0 + \sigma\int_0^t e^{as} \,\mathrm{d}W_s\right)
$$